# How do I test a response within a response in Postman

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postman

I have an mvc controller post action that returns a view. In this view, I then enter some information and the view is supposed to call another action with the model that I am using. Postman returns the first response, no problem, but when I enter the login information and try to submit the form inside the response, nothing happens. How do I properly test this?

Comment: You should show  your action at least.

Comment: Postman is for testing one request-response set at a time. If you are testing your login action, create another request in postman and submit a form with username / password form fields. We can provide more details if you add your code for controller/actions.